# Retrieve whole lyrics from URL

Tags: r, csv, url

I am trying to retrieve the whole lyrics of a band from the web.
I have noticed that they build URLs using `".../firstletter/bandname/songname.html"`

Here is an example.

http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/acdc/itsalongwaytothetopifyouwannarocknroll.html

I was thinkining about creating a function that would `read.csv` the URLs.
That part was kind of easy because I can get the titles by a simple copy paste and save as .csv. Then, use that vector to pass the function for each value in order to construct the URL name.

But I tried to read the first one just to see what it looks like and I found that there will be too much "cleaning the data" if my goal is to build a csv file with each lyric.

```
x <-read.csv(url("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/acdc/itsalongwaytothetopifyouwannarocknroll.html"))
```

I think my approach is not the best (or maybe I need a better data cleaning strategy)

Comment: @Tyler Rinker A lyric it's one lyric from one song. I want every lyric from a band, so yes, I want to do this for multiple songs. I dont understand what you mean by "ugly looking HTML...floating there"

Comment: I want the whole song. I think I don't have the knowledge to do the whole scrapping thing...I really thought that this would be easier...

Comment: Maybe the html comment at the beggining of the lyrics is a good reference to start reading the text. It's even ironic, given what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML page has a tell on where the lyrics begin:

> Usage of azlyrics.com content by any third-party lyrics provider is prohibited by our licensing agreement. Sorry about that.

Taking advantage of that, you can detect this string, and then read everything up to the end of the `div`:

```
m <- readLines("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/acdc/itsalongwaytothetopifyouwannarocknroll.html")

giveaway <- "Sorry about that."
#You can add the full line in case you think one of the lyrics might have this sentence in it.

start <- grep(giveaway, m) + 1 # Where the lyric starts
end <- grep("</div>", m[start:length(m)])[1] + start
# Take the first </div> after the start of the lyric, and then fix the position by adding the start

lyrics <- paste(gsub("<br>|</div>", "", m[start:end]), collapse = "\n") 
#This is just an example of how to clear the remaining tags and join the text.
```

And then:

```
> cat(lyrics) #using cat() prints the line breaks
Ridin' down the highway
Goin' to a show
Stop in all the byways
Playin' rock 'n' roll 
.
.
.
Well it's a long way
It's a long way, you should've told me
It's a long way, such a long way
```

Comment: It's a very straight forward way to do it and it produces a great output. It's the same approach I had but I would have used tons of steps in order to do it. Now I'll try to make the url function to pass the url for the m<-readLines().

Comment: I did take the readLines, the `end` and `start` were a coincidence (I'd say rather intuitive). Still, I must agree that mine is as fragile as yours, since any source code change could affect both. I didn't mean to copy you though, but it ended up very similar. I can delete it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "cleaning the data" means you would be parsing through html tags. I recommend using DOM scraping library that would extract only the text lyrics from the page and save those lyrics to CSV, database or wherever. That way you wouldn't have to do any data cleaning. I don't know what programming language your using, but a simple google search will show you a lot of DOM querying and parsing libraries for any language.
Here is an example with PHP

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/acdc/itsalongwaytothetopifyouwannarocknroll.html');

// Find all images 
$lyrics = $html->find('div.ringtone',1)->next_sibling();
print($lyrics.innertext);
```

now you have lyrics. Save Them.(code not tested);

If your using the R-Language. Use this library here. You will be able to query the DOM and extract the lyrics easily. 
https://github.com/hadley/rvest

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about. I googled it and I still don't understand (I don't another language than R) Could you please explain it a little further? Also, does this require to write html code ?

Comment: I updated my answer but I didn't know the language your using. Now I know, Ill investigate further.

Comment: I had investigated a bit further and I found a R-Language scraping library that is capable of doing what I outlined in my answer with PHP.